# How to count frequency of rows based on values in 3 columns in Rstudio

Tags: r

I have thousands of rows of data which look like this

```
df <- data.frame(
thing_code = c("X123", "X123", "Y123", "Y123", "Y123", "Y123", "Z123", "Z123", "Z123", "Z123", "A456", "A456", "A456", "A456", "A456"),
year = c("2001", "2001", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007"),
country = c("Vietnam", "Vietnam", "US", "US", "Singapore", "Vietnam", "Japan", "Vietnam", "Vietnam", "Cambodia", "Vietnam", "Vietnam", "Iran", "China", "Germany"))
```

wherein I want to count the chunk of contribution of the countries for each thing (represented by thing_code) per year. The categories I want for counting are:

- Vietnam (local country in this example)
- SEAsian (all other southeast asian countries except Vietnam)
- Non-local (other countries except Vietnam and SEAsian)

I want to be able to come up with something like this:

```
# thing_codeyear    location    freq    percentage
# X123      2001    Vietnam     2       1
# Y123      2004    Vietnam     1       0.25
# Y123      2004    Non-local   2       0.5 
# Y123      2004    SEAsian     1       0.25
# Z123      2004    Non-local   1       0.25
# Z123      2004    Vietnam     2       0.5
# Z123      2004    SEAsian     1       0.25
# A456      2007    Vietnam     2       0.4
# A456      2007    Non-local   3       0.6
```

freq will be like a counter for abovementioned categories and percentage will just be the percent of each category's contribution.

So far, my code looks like

```
Vietnam <- df %>% filter(str_detect(country, "Vietnam"))

thing_code_year <- subset(Vietnam, select=c(thing_code, year))
freq <- table(thing_code_year)

frequency <- as.data.frame(freq)
frequency <- frequency %>% filter(Freq!=0)
```

but this only gives me the number for Vietnam and will probably take me a long time to obtain those for other categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give your desired output. You can use `case_when` to create a new variable that specifies the `location` using the logic you described above. Next you `group_by` the code, year, and newly created `location` to calculate the frequency of each category in `location` (Vietnam, SEAsian, Non-local). Then you can `group_by` by code and year to calculate the percentage/proportion of the categories in `location`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  thing_code = c("X123", "X123", "Y123", "Y123", "Y123", "Y123", "Z123", "Z123", "Z123", "Z123", "A456", "A456", "A456", "A456", "A456"),
  year = c("2001", "2001", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2004", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007"),
  country = c("Vietnam", "Vietnam", "US", "US", "Singapore", "Vietnam", "Japan", "Vietnam", "Vietnam", "Cambodia", "Vietnam", "Vietnam", "Iran", "China", "Germany"))

SEAsian <- c("Vietnam", "Singapore", "Cambodia")

df %>% 
  mutate(location = case_when(
    country == "Vietnam" ~ "Vietnam",
    country %in% SEAsian[SEAsian != "Vietnam"] ~ "SEAsian",
    !country %in% SEAsian ~ "Non-local"
  )) %>% 
  group_by(thing_code, year, location) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n()) %>% 
  group_by(thing_code, year) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = freq/sum(freq))
```

Output:

```
  thing_code year  location   freq percentage
  <fct>      <fct> <chr>     <int>      <dbl>
1 A456       2007  Non-local     3       0.6 
2 A456       2007  Vietnam       2       0.4 
3 X123       2001  Vietnam       2       1   
4 Y123       2004  Non-local     2       0.5 
5 Y123       2004  SEAsian       1       0.25
6 Y123       2004  Vietnam       1       0.25
7 Z123       2004  Non-local     1       0.25
8 Z123       2004  SEAsian       1       0.25
9 Z123       2004  Vietnam       2       0.5
```

Comment: I get this error `Error: n() should only be called in a data context`? I think it's cuz of `summarise(freq = n())`

Comment: My bad. The summarise function is also present in the "plyr" package. Solved using dplyr::summarise(freq = n()).